# How to retrieve last subscribers with sorting such as in youtube?

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-js-client

I use simple method, such us

```html
buildApiRequest('GET','/youtube/v3/channels',
{
  'mySubscribers': true,
  'maxResults': MaxResult,
  'part': 'snippet'
}
```

It works, but in result I can't see how I can sort them.
I need last MaxResult subscribers, and I wanna sort them by join date on my channel.

Comment: Please describe any issues you are having with your current solution.   You may want to google how to sort a list in the language of your choice.    Google isnt going to sort the response for you.   Please add your sorting code and we will help you if we can.

Comment: Not all methods in the Youtube api support sorting.  You will have to download the data it sort it locally on your machine.

Comment: In API I couldn't find query wich can retrive date and time when my subscribers subsribed to my channel. Can you tell, how I can sort by subscribed day without general sorting argument, subsribed data? P.S. what u mean under 'download data' ?

Comment: What makes you think this data is available?   To my knowledge subscribers does not return people who have subscribed to a channel or the date they subscribed.   I believe it is simply a list of channels **you** have subscribed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [subscriptions.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) and subscriberSnippet with myRecentSubscribers set to true returns a list of resent subscribers to your channel.  It does not return all of them.

If you check the response you will notice there is no date.  You will not be able to see when someone subscribed.

```
"subscriberSnippet": {
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "channelId": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,0
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    }
```

The order parameter should allow you to order them by title you cant change the parameter it uses to sort on.

```
buildApiRequest('GET',
            '/youtube/v3/subscriptions',
            {'part': 'subscriberSnippet',
             'myRecentSubscribers': 'true',
              'order', 'alphabetical'});
```

**Response**

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#subscriptionListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/wLsZnuAVb0T9-bdRdCnreaWBHNM\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 7,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

  "kind": "youtube#subscription",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/3_huGriwUWV4fbbzcclmEoNYJ3w\"",
   "id": "moP_YQe1scKJgrI0udrz3B2tJTmRwvz4ev3R2_L4JmI",
   "subscriberSnippet": {
    "title": "Kortney W",
    "description": "",
    "channelId": "UC33FFHTxOZ6NRZAp9afsRBw",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-T6Sn1ur07bk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/BSSSRckoD4k/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-T6Sn1ur07bk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/BSSSRckoD4k/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-T6Sn1ur07bk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/BSSSRckoD4k/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {


   "kind": "youtube#subscription",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/UVJds9Q4d24quS-sEG8Qw_3MBzU\"",
   "id": "gI5QI3teCs8unbR7__8oVg7KlRfOtWQYR70kXNkS4PY",
   "subscriberSnippet": {
    "title": "TheCorty",
    "description": "",
    "channelId": "UC-0O3PZ0VPNySP2bNFAPDIA",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-8C6KXmEqDho/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/1roVNa2yF0o/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-8C6KXmEqDho/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/1roVNa2yF0o/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-8C6KXmEqDho/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/1roVNa2yF0o/s800-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

1. this is only going to work if you own the channel
2. it does not return all of your subscribers just the most recent.
3. There is no date in the response you cant sort by date.
4. you can test this [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list?part=subscriberSnippet&myRecentSubscribers=true&_h=3&) just make sure you authenticate to the correct channel

Comment: I use snippet for part, information from it confused me. Because it retrive info of my channel in title and description. Thanks a lot. Very helpful. P.S. without 'order', 'alphabetical' google transmit with datetime chronology.. if myRecentSubscribers -> true

Comment: Google documentation in general is confusing.  Takes a while to learn to read it.

Comment: I can't understand how I must use nextPageToken. I tried to add it as param, but API always returns to me same result as in first page. Where in PHP I must use that token for generation next maxresult information?

`$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$channel = $youtube->subscriptions->listSubscriptions('subscriberSnippet', array('myRecentSubscribers' => true, 'maxResults' => 5, 'pageToken' => 'CC0QAQ'));`

In this situation I get new pageToken, but information didn't updated.

Comment: As example I got totalResults=84, resultsPerPage=5, used nextpagetoken as third page, but information given from first page instead.

Comment: make sure you are actually running the new request and not the original one.